# undefined reference to 'gvr_buffer_viewport_set_source_layer'

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-vr-sdk

I am trying to use `SetSourceLayer(int)` and void `SetMultiviewLayers(int32_t num_layers)` in from gvr.h in my application. I have included `compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.100.0'` in build.gradle. But I am getting error :

```
error: undefined reference to 'gvr_buffer_viewport_set_source_layer' 
error: undefined reference to 'gvr_buffer_spec_set_multiview_layers'
```

I have latest sdk and ndk installed and `minSdkVersion 21`